# Analogue of the transaction in HBase

Tags: java, transactions, nosql, hbase

I have a small problem - I can't understand how to create transaction (or analogue of it) in [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/). For example, there are two tables, and I want to insert value in the first and update value in the second table. I've found that [HTable](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html) has method:

```
void batch(List<Row> actions, Object[] results)
//Method that does a batch call on Deletes, Gets and Puts.
```

But it works only with one table. Googling, I found class [MultiAction](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/MultiAction.html):

> Container for Actions (i.e. Get, Delete, or Put), which are grouped by
>   regionName. Intended to be used with HConnectionManager.processBatch()

Is it that what I'm looking for? If yes, then I can't understand what is [region](http://hbase.apache.org/book/regions.arch.html).
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HBase does not support transaction.
While you have something around atomicity on single table you've got noting like transaction if you need to update more than one.
Transactions means 4 things that go by the acronym [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). in a nutshell

- Atomicity - changes in a transaction occur together ("all or nothing").
- Consistency - state should remain valid
- Isolation - operations outside the transaction cannot see half-changes (intermediate inconsistent states)
- Durability  - changes should persist

You'd have to change HBase code to get Isolation but if you can relax that requirement  you can implement a transaction coordinator that would roughly do something like

- save what needs to be done in the transaction in a special table (transaction log)
- perform first change
- perform second change
- verify that the steps where done and mark the transaction as completed
- when recovering go to the transaction log and complete/rollback changes

Note that because you don't have isolation sometimes rolling back is not an option so you'd need to implement compensation logic (also take a look at the [saga pattern](http://rgoarchitects.bit.ly/4xNwpp))

Answer (score 2):

There are some projects aimed at providing a transactional layer on top of HBase, like [Omid](https://github.com/yahoo/omid), which I contribute to.